# C# TWAIN interaction

Tags: c#, wpf, imaging, image-scanner, twain

I'm trying to set up a C# application which uses TWAIN [example from code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/twaindotnet.aspx)

This works fine except that I need to cast `Form` to `IMessageFilter` and 
call `IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage()` to catch TWAIN callbacks. 
Also I need to start this filtering by calling

```
Application.AddMessageFilter();
```

Is there a way to do same thing in WPF Window? (To add message filter and catch TWAIN callbacks).

Another totally high level question:
Does anybody know about alternative C# TWAIN libraries\wrappers?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try it with the `ComponentDispatcher.ThreadFilterMessage` event.
 As far as I understand, it serves the same purpose in *WPF* as `Application.AddMessageFilter()` in *WinForms*.

Answer (score 9):

I've just wrapped up the code from Thomas Scheidegger's article ([CodeProject: .NET TWAIN image scanning](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/twaindotnet.aspx)) into [github project](https://github.com/tmyroadctfig/twaindotnet)

I've cleaned up the API a bit and added WPF support, so check it out. :)

It has a simple WPF application that shows how the message filtering works with WPF.

Answer (score 0):

I thought TWAIN is considered obsolete. Maybe take a look at [WIA](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/device/stillimage/WIA-arch.mspx), that does this job since WinXP. There is also [a sample](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/wiascriptingdotnet.aspx) at codeproject.
About the WPF related question, no idea, I only used it in windows forms apps.

Comment: driAn, TWAIN is *older* but not obsolete. It has vast devices support.
Also, my scanner does not (oddly) support WIA.

Comment: Well, microsoft considers it being obsolete, they suggest using WIA instead.

Comment: Hmm... There's no causal relation between Microsoft opinions and consensus reality, in either direction. I work with TWAIN, and at least for document scanning, WIA is obsolete and has been since it was introduced. They introduced it during a brief phase when they were excited about clobbering Apple. Then the Burning Eye turned to other things, and it has languished ever since.  I recommend it for digital cameras though.