# WPF equivalent of Application.AddMessageFilter (Windows Forms)

Tags: wpf, windows, winapi, interop

I was using `Application.AddMessageFilter()` in my `WinForms` applications (when working with unmanaged code).

Now I'm switching to `WPF` and can't find this functionality.

Please advice where it can be found or implemented.

Comment: [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/97cc207c-49a7-4a49-9fc1-fdf3b5d904d2/](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/97cc207c-49a7-4a49-9fc1-fdf3b5d904d2/) looks like a solution /edit:
similar question here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476084/c-twain-interaction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476084/c-twain-interaction)

Answer (score 6):

In WPF, you can use `ComponentDispatcher.ThreadFilterMessage` event.

```
ComponentDispatcher.ThreadFilterMessage += ComponentDispatcher_ThreadFilterMessage;
private void ComponentDispatcher_ThreadFilterMessage(ref MSG msg, ref bool handled)
{
     if (msg.message == 513)//MOUSE_LEFTBUTTON_DOWN
     {
         //todo
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to monitor a window message, you can use HwndSource.AddHook method. The following example shows how to use Hwnd.AddHook method. If you want to monitor a application scope message, you can try to use ComponentDispatcher class.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window wnd = new Window();
    wnd.Loaded += delegate
    {
        HwndSource source = (HwndSource)PresentationSource.FromDependencyObject(wnd);
        source.AddHook(WindowProc);
    };
    wnd.Show();
}
private static IntPtr WindowProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
}
```