# Does a WPF Application Actually Need Application.Run?

Tags: wpf

So far, I had assumed that a call to [`System.Windows.Application.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597010%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in a WPF application would start its main message loop and thus provide the UI with its "life". At least, that is what happens in [WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157900%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Gtk#](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=M%3aGtk.Application.Run%28%29), and the same thing seems to be suggested for WPF in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182809/wpf-application-message-loop-and-postthreadmessage), [that blogpost](http://www.ageektrapped.com/blog/the-wpf-application-class-overview-and-gotcha/), and ultimately, the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597010%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) themselves (indirectly, via [`Dispatcher.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.run(v=vs.110).aspx)).

The [documentation for WPF's `Application.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597010%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) emphasizes how important it is to invoke `Run`:

> Run is called to start a WPF application. (...) if you define your Application using code, you will need to explicitly call Run.

It then presents an example that tries to be compelling in its demonstration of how necessary the invocation of `Run` is. And indeed - commenting out the line

```
app.Run();
```

from that example results in an application that just displays a console window for a moment and then quits immediately.

But, well, conveniently, the window in that example is created and displayed in the [`OnStartup` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.onstartup(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `Application` object, which gets invoked after calling `Run`. After moving the window-related code into the `Main` method, the window is at least displayed for a moment:

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{
    CustomApplication app = new CustomApplication();
    //app.Run();

    Window window = new Window();
    window.Show();
}
```

Obviously, that is because with `window` being non-modal, execution continues right after the window is displayed and the application reaches its end right away. So, if we show `window` modally, things look better:

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{
    //CustomApplication app = new CustomApplication();
    //app.Run();

    Window window = new Window();
    window.ShowDialog();
}
```

Now, the window is displayed just as usual. Note that I have meanwhile commented out not only the `Run` invocation, but the instantiation of the `Application` object altogether. Checking with some stepwise execution confirms that [`Application.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.current(v=vs.110).aspx) is always `null`, so there is no `Application` instance throughout the lifetime of this application and `Application.Run` is effectively never called - yet, the application appears to be responsive.

**Does `ShowDialog` perform its own invocation of `Dispatcher.Run`? If so, why the insistence in the docs to call `Application.Run`? Is there anything else going to break that I didn't encounter in this minimal test if I do not have an `Application` object or an invocation of `Application.Run` in my code?**

*Some context: I am in a situation where by default, there is no `Application` instance around (launching a new [`AppDomain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and serving my WPF-based GUI from there - `Application.Current` is `null` by default in the secondary `AppDomain`, and I am bypassing the default entry point in my primary `AppDomain` as I do not want the primary `AppDomain` to host the main window, hence I have to decide whether or not to call `Application.Run` myself there). Therefore, I am attempting to find out whether calling `Application.Run` can cause any problems, or whether* not *calling it will be painful in any way.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `ShowDialog` does start its own dispatcher loop -- otherwise the window would not be able to process window messages and it would either close immediately or "hang". It does this by creating a new [`DispatcherFrame`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherframe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and calling [`Dispatcher.PushFrame`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.pushframe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on it.

`Application.Run` doesn't do anything super important other than creating a window and synchronously running a dispatcher loop, so there should not be any problems with what you are doing here.